# bash script - printing a value of an array based on the value of another array

Tags: bash, array, case

I have two arrays and want to print a value from ARRAY2 depending on the applicable value in ARRAY1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARRAY1=(bb.service.sql bw.service.sql)
ARRAY2=(bb bw)

case $ARRAY1[@] in

  ${ARRAY1[1]})
    echo ${ARRAY2[1]} ;;

  *)
    echo "unknown" ;;
esac
```

I m getting `unknown` here though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net and fixing the errors

Comment: In terms of debugging, `echo case $ARRAY1[@] in` just above your existing `case` statement will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

`$ARRAY1` is short for `${ARRAY1[0]}` in `bash` (a weird design copied from ksh).

`$ARRAY1[@]` there is the same as `${ARRAY[0]}[@]`, so the value of the element of index 0 followed by a literal `[@]`. While in many languages and many shells (starting with `csh`, the first shell to have had arrays) you can index arrays with `$array[1]`, in bash, like in ksh, you need `${array[1]}` instead. It was done that way so as not to break backward compatibility with the Bourne shell that did not have arrays.

`${array[@]}` would expand to all the elements of the array, but here since `case` it only to match strings, the elements are concatenated with spaces and that's what `case` will match against.

Also note that when you assign an array with `array=(foo bar)`, `foo` goes in `${array[0]}`, not 1 (same as in ksh, but unlike most other shells, including zsh where that `array=(values...)` syntax comes from.

In any case, it's not clear to me what you want to do with that.

Maybe you want to map `bb` to `bb.service.sql` instead, in which case, you'd rather use an associative array:

```
#! /bin/bash -
typeset -A map=(
  [bb]=bb.service.sql
  [bw]=bw.service.sql
)
first_parameter=${1?}
corresponding_sql=${map[$first_parameter]?}
```

(the `?`s to error out, if the variables are not set).